# Dreamweaver convert frames to divs

Tags: html, frame, dreamweaver

I have an index.html that's split into 3 frames. I want to change it to divs. 
The "convert tables to ap divs" is grayed out, is there anything I can do? I was following the instructions from here: http://www.ehow.com/how_8598389_convert-frames-divs-dreamweaver.html

If the convert doesn't work for frames is there any other way to do it?

Thanks,
AZ

Comment: Belongs on: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would also help to see the code you're trying to convert.

Comment: <html dir="ltr">

 <head><title>Apparatus</title></head>
 
 <frameset rows="115,*" border="">
  <frameset cols="70%,30%" border="">
   <frame src="logo.php" name="logo" scrolling="no">
   <frame src="login.php" name="login" scrolling="no">
  </frameset>
  <frameset cols="151,*" border="">
   <frame src="menu.php" name="menu">
   <frame src="home.php" name="main">
  </frameset>
 </frameset>
 
</html>